# Oracle length() function returning incorrect value

Tags: sql, oracle

I just found some... I don't know what I'd call it but here goes:

```
SELECT part_num, 
       length(trim(part_num)) 
  FROM part_programs 
 WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

...results:

```
PART_NUM        LENGTH(TRIM(PART_NUM))
--------------- ----------------------
THAB256         8
THA1256674      11
THA1256674GU    13
THA1257141      11
THA1257141FR    13
THA1257141FR1   14
THA1257141TD    13
THA2002013      11
THA2002013MI    13
THA2002013MI1   14
```

The returned integer from length() call actually returns 1 + realLength of the values.

I'm not sure where to begin, anyone care to shed a light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try looking at the detail of the field by using the built in DUMP function

```
SELECT part_num,
       length(trim(part_num)),
       dump( trim( part_num ) )
  FROM part_programs  
 WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

This will return data like

```
Typ=96 Len=6: 79,114,97,99,108,101
```

from this query

```
SELECT dump( 'Oracle' ) from dual
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a non-visible character (like a CR) on the end of those part_nums that TRIM() does not remove.

Just a guess. :-)

Try bracketing them with '[' || part_num || ']' in the select and see if you notice some extra  white-space on either side of the field.

Comment: That sounds like a fair enough guess - to test, execute an insert statement with known data and see what that outputs as a length. Also, if you have UNIX and an SQL command line interface, try something like "oracle select part_num from part_programs | od -xcb" to get a hex dump of the output - that might show up dodgy characters in the column.

Comment: Bracketing is a nice idea - I like that. To get the real length you might try something like: length(trim(replace(replace(part_num, chr(10)),chr(13))))